# Why does merge automatically set the latest dataset I created?

Tags: merge, sas

I'm having trouble using `merge` and I realized why : besides the table I want to merge, SAS seems to automatically add the latest table I created. The following code illustrates the issue :

```
DATA table1;      /* to be merged dataset no 1*/ 
input X rep Y Z;
cards;
1 1 0 2
5 1 2 6
5 2 5 2
;
run;

proc sort; by x rep; run;

data table3;     /* to be merged dataset no 2 */
input X;
cards;
1 
5 
5
10
10
15
;
run;

proc sort; by x; run;

data table3;    /* rep stands for 'replicate' and makes sure there is no uniqueness issue */
set table3; by x;
retain rep;
if first.x then rep=0;
rep=rep+1;  /*rep+1; */
run;

data table2;    /*some other table having nothing to do with the merge*/
input Y W;
cards;
1 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
3 0
8 0
;
run;

data merge1;
merge table3 table1; 
by x rep;
set nobs=n;
run;
```

When it is submitted, the log shows that the latest table created (table2) is somehow used to create merge1. Actually, table2 columns are added to what merge1 should be.[image: a wild table2 appears !]

Trying to understand this, I found that this doesn't happen if I get rid of the `set nobs=n;` line in the definition of merge1.

I couldn't find why on the internet but I found several documents warning about how `merge` can be tricky (but for other reasons)...

Therefore, my questions are :

- Why does this happen and how to fix it ? (I need `nobs` in my calculations) I would be able to escape the issue doing the merge and the following treatment in separated data steps but I would like to understand the whole thing and how to properly deal with it.
- Is `merge` the best way to add values in only one column of a dataset ? (here, table1 column X is updated by table3, but Y and Z are not yet). (this question will be secondary if the first one is answered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set nobs=n` statement is reading in `table2` implicitly from `&SYSLAST`.

It's like doing

```
data table2 ;
  /* some stuff */
run ;

data want ;
  set ; /* implicity use &SYSLAST - table2 in this case - as input dataset */
run ;
```

I'm unsure what you intend to achieve with `set nobs=n`, but the merge datastep without `set nobs=n` will return `Y` and `Z` values based on the join criteria.

EDIT:

```
data merge1;
  merge table3 table1 end=eof ; 
  by x rep;
  if eof then call symputx('NOBS',_n_) ;
run;
data merge1 ;
  set merge1 ;
  NOBS = &NOBS ;
run ;
```

Output of `merge1`

```
 X    rep    Y    Z    NOBS

 1     1     0    2      6
 5     1     2    6      6
 5     2     5    2      6
10     1                 6
10     2                 6
15     1                 6
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer ! I actually would like n to be the number of rows in merge1. Do I have to start a new data step to get that ?